# Analyzing the ratio of the period of a small and large angle oscillation

Tags: classical-mechanics, oscillators

I'm trying to understand how the angle of an oscillation really affects the period of a given system. For angles where $\theta_{0} \ll 1 \text{ rad}$, the approximation is well known as:

$$
T_{small} = 2\pi \sqrt{\frac{l}{g}}
$$
Whereas, for larger angles, outside this limit, we have that the period is given by:

$$
T_{large}= \sqrt{\frac{8l}{g}}\int_{0}^{\theta_{0}}\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{\cos\theta - \cos\theta_{0}}}
$$

Lets just say that $l/g =1 $ as i'm not interested in any specific case. So, when calculating the $T_{large}$ I find the problem that when $\theta_{0} = 0 $ I have an infinite integrand, which is bad. So, as in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1139420/period-of-a-simple-pendulum), I use the [complete elliptic integral of the first kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind)
Where I now need to calculate,

$$
K(k) = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2(u)}}du
$$

so then I can now find:

$$
T = 4 \sqrt{\frac{l}{2g}}K(\sin\frac{\theta_0}{2})
$$
My problem is, when analysing the ration of $T_{small}/T_{large}$ I find the following plot: [image]

which is very strange to me, because I think that as $\theta_0$ increases the ratio should increase asymptotically.

worth noting, I'm using the interval of $ 0 < \theta_0 < 0.99 \pi $

Can somebody please explain me what I'm not understanding here?

Comment: Are you sure the analysis is physically correct when the angle is greater than $90^\circ $ or $ \pi/2^{\rm c}$?

Comment: Your math looks OK, but beware there are two (or more!) notation conventions for elliptic integrals. Some sources (including Wolfram alpha) define your integral as $K(k^2)$ not $K(k)$. That might explain why your numerical results are wrong.

Comment: @Farcher You are nearly right, but the OP's model is correct for $\theta_0 < \pi$ (not $2\pi$ as in the OP's final graph.) But the OP's numerical results are wrong, since when $\theta_0 \to \pi$ the period goes to infinity.

Comment: @alephzero hmmm, I'm using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind) as a reference. I think that maybe because 360º is basically 0º, so the aproximation starts to work again?

Answer (score 0):

pendulum  kinetic energy is:

$$T_k=m\frac 12 l^2\dot{\vartheta}^2$$

the potential energy is

$$U=-m\,g\,l\,\cos(\vartheta)$$

thus the energy $~E=T+U$  is conserved , from here you obtain

$$E=m\frac 12 l^2\dot{\vartheta}^2+m\,g\,l\,\cos(\vartheta)=E_0\\
E_0=-m\,g\,l\,\cos \left( \vartheta _{{0}} \right)\\
\Rightarrow\\
\frac {d\vartheta}{dt}=\pm{\frac {\sqrt {2}\sqrt {g}\sqrt {\cos \left( \vartheta  \right) -\cos
 \left( \vartheta _{{0}} \right) }}{\sqrt {l}}}
$$

thus:

$$T_{L}=2\sqrt{\frac{l}{2\,g}}\int_{-\vartheta_0}^{+\vartheta_0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos(\vartheta)-\cos(\vartheta_0)}}\,d\vartheta
\,\\
T_S=2\pi\sqrt{\frac lg}\\
\frac{T_S}{T_L}=\pi\,\sqrt{2}\int_{-\vartheta_0}^{+\vartheta_0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos(\vartheta)-\cos(\vartheta_0)}}\,d\vartheta$$

**result**

$0.1\le ~\vartheta_0~ \le \pi$

for $~\vartheta_0=1.59~$ the result is imaginer

[image]